# Is SYN + FIN segment blocked by Linux stack?

Tags: tcp, linux-kernel, scapy

I'm trying to send a TCP segment with SYN+FIN control bits set on a Linux machine (kernel 3.16) to another one for testing purposes with scapy:

```
from scapy.all import *

sport = random.randrange(1024, 65535)
dport = 45000

pkt = IP(dst=X.X.X.X)/TCP(sport=sport, dport=dport, flags="SF")
send(pkt)
```

The segment can be seen with wireshark on sender, however, it does not seem to be sent to X.X.X.X as wireshark on that machine do not see the segment at all. Is Linux kernel blocking the sending of SYN+FIN segments (as this kind of control bits combination in a segment should never occur)? Else, what could be the reason for such behaviour? How can I achieve sending SYN+FIN segments?

Comment: Why? Is it legal to send a FIN over a connection that hasn't been established yet?

Comment: It isn't legal no. It is to test how Linux stack reacts when receiving one.

Answer (score 1):

Generally a segment will never have both SYN & FIN flags set at the same time as it violates TCP rules. It really depends on the OS but TCP will usually send a RST back.

There is a similar thread regarding this matter, see [What happens when SYN and FIN flags in TCP headers are both set to 1?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12534/what-happens-when-syn-and-fin-flags-in-tcp-headers-are-both-set-to-1)

Comment: Purpose is to actually test, sending a real segment, to corroborate what the RFC states. "It really depends on the OS": exactly, but theory is not enough here. This question is very OS (Linux) dependant.